# Where can i download Angular JS UI controls?

Tags: angularjs

`Angular JS` replaces `jquery` so all things done in `jquery` can be done from `Angular`. `Jquery` has UI controls from textboxes, datepickers to datatable. So Angular also must have those controls.

With Jquery jquery webssite provides UI control and datatables.net website provides jquery datatables. Likewise for Angular JS what are the controls that the developers typically use and recommended to use, where can i download then?

I need those controls that uses and supports Angular JS 2.0 and can be used with ASP MVC 5!

thanks

Comment: Checkout PrimeNG for Angular2. It is an open source UI component suite. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with your first statement - AngularJS does not replace jQuery - it works along side it.

AngularJS is a MVW Framework - jQuery is not - they can and do co-exist.

[Angular-UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) do a wide variety of controls - they have even implemented many bootstrap controls the "Angular-way".

Currently AngularJS 2 is still in beta - so you will have to wait a while for the community to create lots of plugins - or even give it go yourself. For example the Angular2 - UI bootstrap GitHub [(here)](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/core) is a work in progress and will keep evolving as the Angular2 team release more betas and further stabilise their APIs.

As for ASP MVC compatibility - you should be fine - ASP MVC just renders html - so as long as you're rendering the correct html (maybe with AngularJS directives/controllers in) then you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

[Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) have some good Angular JS UI controls